# How can I fix this if statement php?

Tags: php, if-statement

In my if statement, I have size and gender, look at my code. It cost a problem when my if statement doesn't need size but still need the gender.

For some reason, my website will not detect the size of avatar somewhere, so I don't need the size at the end of this if statement, usually, I should use else when nothing is match to the if statement.

However, I still need to emphasize the gender, what can I fix this problem?

```
<?php
    if ($size <= 48 && $gender=='Female') $custom_avatar_size = '48';
    else if ($size > 48 && $size <= 96 && $gender=='Female') $custom_avatar_size = '96';
    else if ($size > 96 && $size <= 128 && $gender=='Female') $custom_avatar_size = '128';
    else if ($size > 128 && $size <= 256 && $gender=='Female') $custom_avatar_size = '256';
    else if ($size <= 48 && $gender=='Male') $custom_avatar_size = '1';
    else if ($size > 48 && $size <= 96 && $gender=='Male') $custom_avatar_size = '2';
    else if ($size > 96 && $size <= 128 && $gender=='Male') $custom_avatar_size = '3';
    else if ($size > 128 && $size <= 256 && $gender=='Male') $custom_avatar_size = '4';
    else if ($gender=='Female') $custom_avatar_size = '512';//problem is here
    else if ($gender=='Male') $custom_avatar_size = '5';//problem is here
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this -

```
<?php
if ($size <= 48) {
    if ($gender == 'Female') {
        $custom_avatar_size = '48';
    } else if ($gender == 'Male') {
        $custom_avatar_size = '1';
    }
} else if ($size > 48 && $size <= 96) {
    if ($gender == 'Female') {
        $custom_avatar_size = '96';
    } else if ($gender == 'Male') {
        $custom_avatar_size = '2';
    }
} else if ($size > 96 && $size <= 128) {
    if ($gender == 'Female') {
        $custom_avatar_size = '128';
    } else if ($gender == 'Male') {
        $custom_avatar_size = '3';
    }
} else if ($size > 128 && $size <= 256) {
    if ($gender == 'Female') {
        $custom_avatar_size = '256';
    } else if ($gender == 'Male') {
        $custom_avatar_size = '4';
    }
} else {
    if ($gender == 'Female') {
        $custom_avatar_size = '512';
    } else if ($gender == 'Male') {
        $custom_avatar_size = '5';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can check for $size being empty, you can update the last two "else if" statements as follow:

```
else if (empty($size) && $gender=='Female') $custom_avatar_size = '512';
else if (empty($size) && $gender=='Male') $custom_avatar_size = '5';
```